# Как использовать numericUpDown из другого файла

Tags: c#, wpf

Скачал [Toolkit](https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit/tree/master/ExtendedWPFToolkitSolution) так как wpf не содержит элемент NumericUpDown
Не понимаю как использовать его дальше, как подключить его к моему проекту и использовать

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.CostPrice"
    xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="CostPrice" Height="765.278" Width="800">
<Grid ShowGridLines="True" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="412" Margin="0,10,0,-2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="790">

    <xctk:DecimalUpDown Name="myUpDownControl" />
</Grid>
```

Дает ошибку

> тег "DecimalUpDown" не существует в пространстве имен XML "http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit". Строка 72 позиция 10.    WpfApp1 C:\Users\Pasha\source\repos\WpfApp1\WpfApp1\CostPrice.xaml  72

Comment: И что происходит с вашим кодом? Ошибку дает или что?

Comment: Да, мне кажется я не верно что то подключил

Comment: Как вы поставили пакет? Проверил у себя, все успешно установилось. Попробуйте очистить, потом пересобрать проект и только потом попытайтесь добавить контрол в XAML. P.S. Странными вы вещами занимаетесь, ей богу, этот контрол можно легко написать на чистом WPF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Ставим пакет
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2) Дописываем пространство имен
`xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"`
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

3) Когда начинаем указывать пространство имен интеллисенс подсказывает нам, какие есть контролы
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

4) Вот такой `<xctk:IntegerUpDown/>`
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Возможно между п.2 и п.3 необходимо собрать проект, чтобы IntelliSense нормально заработал

Comment: @АндрейNOP возможно, да, скорее всего я сделал сборку машинально, и не запомнил сей факт.

Comment: Спасибо за хорошее объяснение все работает, я не правильно устанавливал пакет, точнее просто бросал в директорию проекта )